# No Grub Menu after installing Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I had a Windows 10 laptop, in which I have created a new drive and installed Ubuntu 17.04.

My Windows is not able to detect Ubuntu and is not showing any GRUB menu on startup. If I change the boot drive from BIOS then only I am able to load Ubuntu.

Any way I can get the GRUB menu here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: You can try to use Boot repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and add the path to windows and then define the boot priority to Ubuntu always, if that doesnt work you can use grub customizer http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Comment: did you install ubuntu in EFI mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)